# Add missing () to mathematical functions

Tags: math-mode

I am trying to get LaTeX to render

```
${f}^\prime = e^{x\,\log \cos x}\,\left(x\,\log \cos x\right)^\prime$
```

as

```
${f}^\prime = e^{x\,\log \left (\cos \left (x  \right )  \right )}\,\left(x\,\log \left (\cos \left (x  \right )  \right )\right)^\prime$
```

thus automatically adding the missing ().
If the functions have more than one argument, the parentheses will already be added (so there's no ambiguity).
Does anyone know a quick and simple way to accomplish this?

Comment: You can define `newcommands` to do this, but you'll have to be careful and they'll probably need to take extra arguments. Perhaps it could be easier to define your own shortcut `newcommands` for commonly used functions, i.e. `\newcommand{\cospar}[1]{\cos\left( #1\right}` for cosine with built in parentheses.

Comment: Sorry, that should have been `\newcommand{\cospar}[1]{\cos\left(#1\right)}`. I missed the last bracket.

Comment: No problem. I probably should have put it in as an answer! Happy TeXing!

Answer (score 1):

The following works if you always write `\log \cos x`

```
\documentclass{article}
\let\Log\log
\def\log \cos x{\Log(\cos(x))}     
\begin{document}

${f}^\prime = e^{x\,\log \cos x}\,(x\,\log \cos x)^\prime$

\end{document}
```

Comment: This also has problem if there is more than one character: `\cos xy` does not produce `cos(xy)`.

Comment: @Peter Gill: That's the reason Herbert wrote: _if you always write `\log \cos x`_, isn't it?

Comment: This is one of the advantages of using plain TeX `\def` for macro definitions.

Comment: @Peter Grill: In my future answers I'll have a special paragraph in bold with informations only for you ...

Comment: :-)  Thanks Herbert. Any help in make this site more useful for me is great. :-) :-)

Answer (score 1):

Not completely, what you wanted, but almost:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand*{\redefinesymbolwitharg}[1]{%
  \expandafter\newcommand\csname ltx#1\endcsname{}%
  \expandafter\let\csname ltx#1\expandafter\endcsname\csname #1\endcsname
  \expandafter\renewcommand\csname #1\endcsname[1]{%
   \csname ltx#1\endcsname\left(##1\right)%
 }%
}

\redefinesymbolwitharg{cos}
\redefinesymbolwitharg{log}

\begin{document}

% You may use \ltxcos, \ltxlog etc. if you need the original definition
% without argument:
${f}^\prime = e^{x \ltxlog \left (\ltxcos \left (x  \right )  \right  )}\,\left(x \ltxlog \left (\ltxcos \left (x  \right )  \right )\right)^\prime$

% But \cos and \log expect an argument now:
${f}^\prime = e^{x \log{\cos x}}\,\left(x \log{\cos x}\right)^\prime$

\end{document}
```

Here for the argument of `\cos` I've used the standard behavior of TeX, that if you don't use argument braces `{`…`}` it uses the first token after the command to be the argument. This would work with each single characters coded with a single byte (e.g. `\cos ß` would fail if you're using `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` but `\cos{ß}` or `\cos \beta` would be correct).

And if you prefer to write `\redefinesymbolwitharg\cos` instead of `\redefinesymbolswitharg{cos}` you may replace definition of `\redefinesymbolwitharg` by:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\redefinesymbolwitharg}[1]{%
  \edef\@tempa{\expandafter\@gobble\string #1}%
  \expandafter\let\csname ltx\@tempa\expandafter\endcsname\csname \@tempa\endcsname
  \expandafter\renewcommand\csname \@tempa\endcsname[1]{%
    \csname ltx\@tempa\endcsname\left(##1\right)%
  }%
}
\makeatother
```

Comment: This has problem if there is more than one character: `\cos xy` does not produce `cos(xy)`.

Comment: @Peter Gill: I've never told something diffent. You have to use `\cos{xy}` in this case. Compare it with usage of `\log` I've shown. That's the reason I've told: _Not completely, what you wanted_.

Comment: I did not mean to imply you said anything different, just thought that should be pointed out. I did this solution at first as well, and only then afterwards realized this problem.  Also, excellent idea to generalize the solution via `\redefinesymbolwitharg` -- that did not occur to me.

Comment: @Peter Grill: In this case, we should tell the user, that omitting the braces may only be done for single characters, that are coded with a single byte and e.g. `\cos ß` instead of `\cos{ß}` would fail using `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`. But is "How TeX finds macro arguments?" the topic?

Answer (score 0):

Mark's suggestion is a good one. But if you don't want to deal with `\newcommand` you can add the "()" without `\left` of `\right` as follows:

```
 $ f^\prime = e^{x\,\log (\cos (x))}\,(x\,\log (\cos (x)))^\prime $
```

The result is almost exactly what you want except for a little difference in the space preceding the brackets.

Comment: That's not quite accurate... Nested brackets are automatically resized when preceded by `\left` and `\right`, while this is not happening otherwise. Plus these two commands let `LaTeX` 'know' that these go in pairs. That is why you have for instance `\right.` that does not produce any visible bracket.

Comment: Thanks Leonardo, but with your solution I would still need to add the brackets manually.

Comment: @CountZero You're right, but in this particular case the presence of '\left \right' is not so relevant. The output looks very similar with or without these commands.

Answer (score 0):

I think Mark's suggestion is the way to go. But, you do need to be aware that there are problems unless you enclose the args of the `\cos` within a `{}` when there is more than one character involved as in the last case here.

This is no different than other functions if you leave out the `{}` as in `$\frac 12a$`,

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\Cos}[1]{\cos\left(#1\right)}%
\begin{document}
${f}^\prime = e^{x\,\log \cos x}\,\left(x\,\log \cos x\right)^\prime$

${f}^\prime = e^{x\,\log \left (\cos \left (x  \right )  \right )}\,\left(x\,\log \left (\cos \left (x  \right )  \right )\right)^\prime$

\bigskip
Now using \textbackslash{}Cos:\par
${f}^\prime = e^{x\,\log \Cos x}\,\left(x\,\log \Cos x\right)^\prime$

${f}^\prime = e^{x\,\log \Cos {x\pi}}\,\left(x\,\log \Cos {x\pi}\right)^\prime$
\end{document}
```