# Sine squared with parentheses for argument

Tags: macros, arguments

I have a number of trig functions raised to some powers, and the arguments are often different from just `t`

```
\sin^2{\frac{2\pi}{T}t}
```

for example

Now, I would like to get the argument to be in parentheses, which I know I can input manually with

```
\sin^2{\left(\frac{2\pi}{T}t\right)}
```

but I would like to get it automatically.

Now, I've tried to redefine the symbol with argument, as shown here https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/35646/106445

but when I try to add the power I get two errors: `Missing { inserted`, and `Missing } inserted`. I assume it's because it's expecting the argument and I have added the power instead. Any workaround?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\newcommand*{\redefinesymbolwitharg}[1]{%
  \expandafter\newcommand\csname ltx#1\endcsname{}%
  \expandafter\let\csname ltx#1\expandafter\endcsname\csname #1\endcsname
  \expandafter\renewcommand\csname #1\endcsname[1]{%
   \csname ltx#1\endcsname\left(##1\right)%
 }%
}

\redefinesymbolwitharg{cos}

\begin{document}

\[\cos{2x}\]
\[\cos^2{2x}\]

\end{document}
```

There is no problem with the first one, but once I add the square as I would normally it breaks

Comment: For me the linked code works fine. Could you please provide a *complete* example that shows the issue?

Comment: For what it is worth, `\sin` does not take an argument.  No braces `{...}` are needed.

Comment: I had no clue, I guess I have always assumed it took one and I always wrote it that way ´\sin{x}´
I've added a complete example

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes right, but I think that OP wants it for correct spacing when using an operator and braces. I add braces *(manually)* for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My (unrequested) advice would be *not* to introduce automatic brackets, and surely not to introduce automatically scaling brackets produced by `\left...\right`. Personally, I find `\cos(x)` rather clearer than `\cos{x}`, and you don't really spare keystrokes (and the braces are quite pointless, since `\cos` doesn't take an argument). As for `\left`/`\right`, there are [enough examples](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/173717/82917) on this site as why their overuse produces often rather bad results.

This being said, the following code (which should never be used under any circumstances `:-)`) might work as desired:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\redefinesymbolwitharg}[1]{%
  \expandafter\let\csname ltx#1\expandafter\endcsname\csname #1\endcsname
  \@namedef{#1}{\@ifnextchar{^}{\@nameuse{#1@}}{\@nameuse{#1@}^{}}}%
  \expandafter\def\csname #1@\endcsname^##1##2{%
     \csname ltx#1\endcsname\ifx!##1!\else^{##1}\fi\mathopen{}\mathclose\bgroup\left(##2\aftergroup\egroup\right)
     }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\[
\cos{x} \quad \cos{\frac1x} \quad \cos^2{y} \quad \sin^{2\alpha+1}\theta
\]

\redefinesymbolwitharg{cos}
\redefinesymbolwitharg{sin}

\[
\cos{x} \quad \cos{\frac1x} \quad \cos^2{y} \quad \sin^{2\alpha+1}\theta
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]