# Automatically add Parentheses to \cos, \sin, \log, ecc. , allowing subscripts

Tags: macros, brackets, automation

I'm sorry if the title suggests a question that has been asked a lot of times (see below), but I couldn't find an answer that also fulfills another need...

As a math teacher, I want my students to get used (at least at the beginning) to always write parenthesis around functions like cos, sin, tan, log, ln, etc., so to have cos(x) instead of cos x. I therefore wanted my LaTeX files to always put (...) around those functions automatically, by calling them as \cos{x}.

For this, I already found more than one question/answer that allows me to achieve this, e.g.

- [Sine squared with parentheses for argument](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/458734/sine-squared-with-parentheses-for-argument)
- [Add missing () to mathematical functions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35636/add-missing-to-mathematical-functions)
- ...

I chose the following version from the first link:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\redefinesymbolwitharg}[1]{%
  \expandafter\let\csname ltx#1\expandafter\endcsname\csname #1\endcsname
  \@namedef{#1}{\@ifnextchar{^}{\@nameuse{#1@}}{\@nameuse{#1@}^{}}}%
  \expandafter\def\csname #1@\endcsname^##1##2{%
     \csname ltx#1\endcsname\ifx!##1!\else^{##1}\fi\mathopen{}\mathclose\bgroup\left(##2\aftergroup\egroup\right)
     }%
}
\makeatother
```

and then call for example

```
\redefinesymbolwitharg{cos}
```

---

The above code allows me to write

```
\cos x + \cos{y} + \cos^{2}{z} + \cos^3{k}
```

by always adding the bracket around the argument, but not to write

```
\cos_a{x}
```

Trying to understand the above code, I see that the @ifnextchar{^} case is specifically handled, but I've not been able to also integrate the "_" case, necessary for e.g. the \log function. Could someone help me to add this functionality to the above code (or suggest another way of achieving this?).

Thank you in advance for any suggestion! :)

---

**Bonus question:**

*Would it also be possible to integrate the case \cos'{x} to be converted in \cos^{'}{x}, and so on for ' ' and ' ' ' ? This is not mandatory, but would improve the writing of a lot of lines...*

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Does a solution have to be pdflatex-based, or are you willing to contemplate lualatex-based solutions? Please advise.

Comment: if you are anyway adding braces around the  argument as in `\cos{y}` why not simply use parens instead `\cos(y)` it requires no definition and is much less likely to conflict with other math macro packages, and requires just the same number of characters in the input?

Comment: @Mico Hi, thank you. I'd like it to be pdflatex-based (it would also be used by other colleagues.

Comment: @David for a couple of reasons:
first of all because \cos x works correctly (I wanted to point out that, for a single variable, both \cos x and \cos{x} work fine).
Secondly, because I automatically get \left( \right) that auto-size to the argument, not having to write them every time (I tend to need them quite often).
At last, because with colleagues we exchange a lot of files, and we went with this syntax since then, so all files work with {} or simply \cos x for the easy cases.

Comment: P.S. as additional info, we never had problems with it, since we always used it only for cos/sin/tan, never needing a subscript, but now wanting to use it also for \log, the \log_{a}^5{x} case made us notice the problem with the subscript. If I replace all the ^ instances with _, it works (not anymore with ^), but having both is my issue here...

Comment: Oh well, I didn't see your reply comment until I already gone ahead and posted a LuaLaTeX-based answer. Hopefully it'll still be useful for some other readers in the future.

Comment: Off-topic: You really *don't* want to use `f^{'}`.  See [difference between \prime and `'` in math mode](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/538395)

Comment: Thanks, that's useful to know!

Comment: What would be the reason for imposing “cos(x)” instead of the simpler and traditional “cos x”? If one wants to use the latter form, what would be the problem?

Comment: It's a bit off-topic for the question, however at the moment it's a feature I want my/our documents to have. From a pedagogic point of view, some kids (not university students!) that start to learn trigonometry tend to see cos as a key on the calculator or as a multiplication (you have no idea how may simplifications I've seen involving sin and cos :D ), and we want to stress out that cos is a function whose argument is given between brackets (at least at the beginning; later on, when this is clear, one can choose his/her own syntax).

Comment: Moreover, they tend to write cos x+y sometimes meaning cos(x+y), sometimes cos(x)+y (maybe it was clear for the writer, but not for the reader), so we want to insist on (sometimes redundant) brackets at the beginning. As a bonus, some formulas can be directly copied to some software (e.g. Maple) for solving, if they have (...) and finally, my personal taste also prefers the usage of (...) (but this is not a reason, only a personal taste).

Comment: "Secondly, because I automatically get \left( \right) " eek no don't do that!!! compare  `$\cos(x)$` and `$\cos\left(x\right)$` the horizontal spacing is completely wrong with `\left` as you lose the `\mathopen` class of the `(`.

Comment: What about having the custom command to implement $\cos\mathopen{}\left(\theta\right)\mathclose{}$ intead?

Comment: or better use mleftright package (see the doc why it needs more than just `\mathclose`) but that's adding yet another layer of complexity on what would be better marked up simply as `\cos(x)`

Comment: Thanks, I added the \mleft( \mright) variant to Ulrich's code below and it works as intended with the spacing, nice to know however about this issue in general!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You say:

> As a math teacher, I want my students to get used (at least at the beginning) to always write parenthesis around functions like cos, sin, tan, log, ln, etc.

*... while it seems that you yourself wish to get used to not having to do so at all in your .tex-input-files. ;-)*

*By the way:*

*What exactly do you want the students to write in parentheses?

The sequence of characters that designates the (name of the) function in question?

Sequences of characters that designate operands/arguments of functions?

Please be precise when imposing new things on learners.*

`\cos`, `\sin`, `\tan`, `\log`, `\ln` are macros which don't process arguments as they serve for typesetting the sequence of characters that designates the (name of the) function in question.

With`$\cos$` (La)TeX does nicely typeset the phrase "cos".

With`$\cos{x}$` (La)TeX does nicely typeset the phrase "cos". Then the sequence `{x}` is processed, yielding the letter `x` in math-font. The curly braces in math-mode prevent linebreaks with the things nested within them. Thus in this situation they are not needed as there is only a single character nested between them which makes considerations regarding linebreaks obsolete.  *(In case I am wrong here/overlooking something here, please drop me a hint and I will correct my answer immediately.)*

You actually ask for a mechanism which automatically detects what belongs to the arguments/operands of the function in question. (*←The further.*)
You may also need a mechanism which automatically detects whether subscripts/​superscripts are to be put between parentheses. (*I think this should be done in cases where the subscript/superscript contains other things than just a single number or just a single variable.*) (*←The latter.*)

In the example below I did not try to implement the latter.

I only tried to implement the further.

I did so by means of an `\@ifnextchar`-based recursive loop which gathers up things until finding a token whose meaning neither equals `_` nor equals `^` nor equals `'`. As long as you don't do things like `\cos\empty\relax{(x)}`,  this probably might be sufficient.

```
\documentclass[landscape, oneside]{article}
%===================[adjust margins/layout for the example]====================
\csname @ifundefined\endcsname{pagewidth}{}{\pagewidth=\paperwidth}%
\csname @ifundefined\endcsname{pdfpagewidth}{}{\pdfpagewidth=\paperwidth}%
\csname @ifundefined\endcsname{pageheight}{}{\pageheight=\paperheight}%
\csname @ifundefined\endcsname{pdfpageheight}{}{\pdfpageheight=\paperheight}%
\textwidth=\paperwidth
\oddsidemargin=1.25cm
\marginparsep=.2\oddsidemargin
\marginparwidth=\oddsidemargin
\advance\marginparwidth-2\marginparsep
\advance\textwidth-2\oddsidemargin
\advance\oddsidemargin-1in
\evensidemargin=\oddsidemargin
\textheight=\paperheight
\topmargin=1.25cm
\footskip=.5\topmargin
{\normalfont\global\advance\footskip.5\ht\strutbox}%
\advance\textheight-2\topmargin
\advance\topmargin-1in
\headheight=0ex
\headsep=0ex
\pagestyle{plain}
\parindent=0ex
\parskip=0ex 
\topsep=0ex
\partopsep=0ex
%==================[eof margin-adjustments]====================================

\makeatletter

\newcommand\gatherargumentloop[1]{%
  % #1 - amount of arguments/operands to gather.
  % Let's create an amount of catcode-12-characters "m" equal to the amount of
  % arguments to gather.
  \expandafter\@gatherargumentloop\expandafter{\romannumeral\number\number#1 000}%
}%
\newcommand\@gatherargumentloop[1]{%
  \if\relax#1\relax\expandafter\@gobble\else\expandafter\@firstofone\fi
  {%
    \@ifnextchar^{\gathersupscript{#1}}{%
      \@ifnextchar_{\gathersubscript{#1}}{%
        \@ifnextchar'{\gatherprimesloop{#1}{}}{%
          \gatherargument{#1}%
        }%
      }%
    }%
  }%
}%
\@ifdefinable\gatherprimesloop{%
  \long\def\gatherprimesloop#1#2'{%
    \@ifnextchar'{\gatherprimesloop{#1}{#2'}}{{#2'}\@gatherargumentloop{#1}}%
  }%
}%
\@ifdefinable\gathersupscript{%
  \long\def\gathersupscript#1^#2{%
     ^{#2}\@gatherargumentloop{#1}%
  }%
}%
\@ifdefinable\gathersubscript{%
  \long\def\gathersubscript#1_#2{%
     _{#2}\@gatherargumentloop{#1}%
  }%
}%
\newcommand\gatherargument[1]{%
  \@ifnextchar({\@@gatherargument{#1}}{\@gatherargument{#1}}%
}%
\newcommand\@gatherargument[2]{%
  \UD@CheckWhetherLeadingTokens{#2}{\left(}{.}{\LeftLeftParen}{#2}{%
    \UD@CheckWhetherLeadingTokens{#2}{(}{.}{\LeftParen}{#2}{%
      \UD@CheckWhetherLeadingTokens{#2}{ (}{.}{\SpaceLeftParen}{#2}{%
        \UD@CheckWhetherLeadingTokens{#2}{ \left(}{.}{\SpaceLeftLeftParen}{#2}{%
          (#2)%
        }%
      }%
    }%
  }% 
  \expandafter\@gatherargumentloop\expandafter{\@gobble#1}%
}%
\@ifdefinable\@@gatherargument{%
  \long\def\@@gatherargument#1#2){%
    #2)%
    \expandafter\@gatherargumentloop\expandafter{\@gobble#1}%
  }%
}%
%==========[code for checking leading token-sequences in arguments]============
%% Check whether argument is empty:
%%.............................................................................
%% \UD@CheckWhetherNull{<Argument which is to be checked>}%
%%                     {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                       which is to be checked is empty>}%
%%                     {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                       which is to be checked is not empty>}%
%%
%% The gist of this macro comes from Robert R. Schneck's \ifempty-macro:
%% <https://groups.google.com/forum/#!original/comp.text.tex/kuOEIQIrElc/lUg37FmhA74J>
\newcommand\UD@CheckWhetherNull[1]{%
  \romannumeral0\expandafter\@secondoftwo\string{\expandafter
  \@secondoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter{\string#1}\expandafter
  \@secondoftwo\string}\expandafter\@firstoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter
  \@secondoftwo\string}\@firstoftwo\expandafter{} \@secondoftwo}%
  {\@firstoftwo\expandafter{} \@firstoftwo}%
}%
%
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Exchange two arguments. (From each argument an outermost level of 
%% surrounding braces will be removed if present.)
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
\newcommand\UD@Exchange[2]{#2#1}%
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Check whether argument's leading tokens form a specific 
%% token-sequence that does not contain explicit character tokens of 
%% category code 1 or 2:
%%.............................................................................
%% \UD@CheckWhetherLeadingTokens{<argument which is to be checked>}%
%%                              {<a <token sequence> without explicit 
%%                                character tokens of category code
%%                                1 or 2>}%
%%                              {a <single non-space token> that does 
%%                                _not_ occur in <token sequence> >}%
%%                              {<internal token-check-macro>}%
%%                              {<tokens to be delivered in case
%%                                <argument which is to be checked> has
%%                                <token sequence> as leading tokens>}%
%%                              {<tokens to be delivered in case 
%%                                <argument which is to be checked>
%%                                does not have <token sequence> as
%%                                leading tokens>}%
\newcommand\UD@CheckWhetherLeadingTokens[4]{%
  \romannumeral0\UD@CheckWhetherNull{#1}%
  {\UD@Exchange{ }\expandafter\@secondoftwo}%
  {\expandafter\@secondoftwo\string{\expandafter
   \UD@@CheckWhetherLeadingTokens#4#3#1#2}{}}%
}%
\newcommand\UD@@CheckWhetherLeadingTokens[1]{%
  \expandafter\UD@CheckWhetherNull\expandafter{\@firstoftwo{}#1}%
  {\UD@Exchange{\@firstoftwo}}{\UD@Exchange{\@secondoftwo}}%
  {\UD@Exchange{ }{\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
   \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter}\expandafter\expandafter
   \expandafter}\expandafter\@secondoftwo\expandafter{\string}%
}%
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% \UD@internaltokencheckdefiner{<internal token-check-macro>}%
%%                              {<token sequence>}%
%% Defines <internal token-check-macro> to snap everything 
%% until reaching <token sequence>-sequence and spit that out
%% nested in braces.
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
\newcommand\UD@internaltokencheckdefiner[2]{%
  \@ifdefinable#1{\long\def#1##1#2{{##1}}}%
}%
\UD@internaltokencheckdefiner{\LeftLeftParen}{\left(}%
\UD@internaltokencheckdefiner{\LeftParen}{(}%
\UD@internaltokencheckdefiner{\SpaceLeftParen}{ (}%
\UD@internaltokencheckdefiner{\SpaceLeftLeftParen}{ \left(}%
%=======[end ofcode for checking leading token-sequences in arguments]=========

\makeatother

\newcommand\mycos{\cos\gatherargumentloop{1}}
\newcommand\mysin{\sin\gatherargumentloop{1}}
\newcommand\mytan{\tan\gatherargumentloop{1}}
\newcommand\mycot{\cot\gatherargumentloop{1}}
\newcommand\mylog{\log\gatherargumentloop{1}}
\newcommand\myln{\ln\gatherargumentloop{1}}

% Like \cos, \sin, \tan, \log, \ln, but with two operands:
\makeatletter
\newcommand\add{\mathop{\operator@font add}\nolimits}%
\makeatother

\newcommand\myadd{\add\gatherargumentloop{2}}

\begin{document}

The $\cos$-game:

\medskip

{\footnotesize\verb|$\mycos x + \mycos{y} + \mycos^{2+3}{z} + \mycos^3{k} + \mycos_{a_1}{x} + \mycos'''''_{a_1}{x} +  \mycos'''''_{a_1}(x) + \mycos'''''_{a_1}{(x)}$|:}

$\mycos x + \mycos{y} + \mycos^{2+3}{z} + \mycos^3{k} + \mycos_{a_1}{x} + \mycos'''''_{a_1}{x} +  \mycos'''''_{a_1}(x) + \mycos'''''_{a_1}{(x)}$

\bigskip

The $\sin$-game:

\medskip

{\footnotesize\verb|$\mysin x + \mysin{y} + \mysin^{2+3}{z} + \mysin^3{k} + \mysin_{a_1}{x} + \mysin'''''_{a_1}{x} + \mysin'''''_{a_1}(x) + \mysin'''''_{a_1}{(x)}$|:}

$\mysin x + \mysin{y} + \mysin^{2+3}{z} + \mysin^3{k} + \mysin_{a_1}{x} + \mysin'''''_{a_1}{x} + \mysin'''''_{a_1}(x) + \mysin'''''_{a_1}{(x)}$

\bigskip

The $\tan$-game:

\medskip

{\footnotesize\verb|$\mytan x + \mytan{y} + \mytan^{2+3}{z} + \mytan^3{k} + \mytan_{a_1}{x} + \mytan'''''_{a_1}{x} + \mytan'''''_{a_1}(x) + \mytan'''''_{a_1}{(x)}$|:}

$\mytan x + \mytan{y} + \mytan^{2+3}{z} + \mytan^3{k} + \mytan_{a_1}{x} + \mytan'''''_{a_1}{x} + \mytan'''''_{a_1}(x) + \mytan'''''_{a_1}{(x)}$

\bigskip

The $\cot$-game:

\medskip

{\footnotesize\verb|$\mytan x + \mytan{y} + \mytan^{2+3}{z} + \mytan^3{k} + \mytan_{a_1}{x} + \mytan'''''_{a_1}{x} + \mytan'''''_{a_1}(x) + \mytan'''''_{a_1}{(x)}$|:}

$\mycot x + \mycot{y} + \mycot^{2+3}{z} + \mycot^3{k} + \mycot_{a_1}{x} + \mycot'''''_{a_1}{x} + \mycot'''''_{a_1}(x) + \mycot'''''_{a_1}{(x)}$

\bigskip

The $\log$-game:

\medskip

{\footnotesize\verb|$\mylog x + \mylog{y} + \mylog^{2+3}{z} + \mylog^3{k} + \mylog_{a_1}{x} + \mylog'''''_{a_1}{x} + \mylog'''''_{a_1}(x) + \mylog'''''_{a_1}{(x)}$|:}

$\mylog x + \mylog{y} + \mylog^{2+3}{z} + \mylog^3{k} + \mylog_{a_1}{x} + \mylog'''''_{a_1}{x} + \mylog'''''_{a_1}(x) + \mylog'''''_{a_1}{(x)}$

\bigskip

The $\ln$-game:

\medskip

{\footnotesize\verb|$\myln x + \myln{y} + \myln^{2+3}{z} + \myln^3{k} + \myln_{a_1}{x} + \myln'''''_{a_1}{x} + \myln'''''_{a_1}(x) + \myln'''''_{a_1}(x)$|:}

$\myln x + \myln{y} + \myln^{2+3}{z} + \myln^3{k} + \myln_{a_1}{x} + \myln'''''_{a_1}{x} + \myln'''''_{a_1}(x) + \myln'''''_{a_1}(x)$

\bigskip

The $\add$-game:

\medskip

{\footnotesize\verb|$\myadd xy + \myadd{x}{y} + \myadd^{2+3}{y}{z} + \myadd^3{k}{l} + \myadd_{a_1}{x}{y} + \myadd'''''_{a_1}{x}{y} + \myadd'''''_{a_1}(x)(y) + \myadd'''''_{a_1}{(x)}{(y)}$|:}

$\myadd xy + \myadd{x}{y} + \myadd^{2+3}{y}{z} + \myadd^3{k}{l} + \myadd_{a_1}{x}{y} + \myadd'''''_{a_1}{x}{y} + \myadd'''''_{a_1}(x)(y) + \myadd'''''_{a_1}{(x)}{(y)}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, wow I was not hoping for such a detailed and complex answer, thanks! I'll try to understand the passages to see what you are doing, but the result looks exactly what I was looking for! The only issue is that, to be able to use all existing files, I'd need to overwrite the standard \cos function to do what your \mycos function does, would it be possible? (in my original code I had a \let \Oldcos \cos to store the original function to be restored if needed, but then wrote \cos{x} in the document to achieve the "new" definition).

Comment: To answer your initial questions: I'm doing this it in the LaTeX documents because, since I want my students at the beginning to do it, I'm "forcing" myself (and the collagues) to do the same in LaTeX, even if by mistake I write \cos x (it's not a laziness issue, but rather a safety measure), plus I always avoid to have to write \left( \right) every time.

Comment: For the parentheses, I want to stress out that cos is a function, like any f(x), so cos is the name, x the argument of the function ad is passed to it between brackets (I know it sounds trivial, but stuff like cos5/cos3=5/3 are for some kids at the beginning just normal, when in physics courses cos is presented as a key on the calculator, not getting what the function cos is... Having brackets to encapsulate the argument of a function is one way of stressing out that it is a function). These are however just pedagocical remarks that have nothing to do with the technical problem ;)

Comment: P.S. about the $\cos{x}$question: if you look at my original post, I used that (very short) code to achieve the result of having the command $\cos{x}$ do what I need, except for the fact that it only handles either the ^ or the _ case, but I couldn't modify the code to make it handle both; the function \cos is then overwritten to allow the usage of $\cos{x}$, passing an argument to it to be encapsulated between brackets.
-
[I'm sorry if I'm writing all these messages, but I always exceed the max characters for a single post to answer your questions... )]

Comment: Sorry I was also forgetting one question: your code works perfectly everywhere, except when I write \section{The $\mysin{x}$ function}: is it normal?

Comment: When a user-defined command is used in a "moveable"  argument, it needs to be protected.  (`\section` is moveable, as it produces an entry for a table of contents.)  In such a case, enter `\protect\mysin`, etc.

Comment: Thank you Barbara, that solved the issue perfectly! I also managed to overwrite the default cos function by saving it to \Oldcos and then calling \renewcmd \cos{\Oldcos \gatherargumentloop{1}}.

Comment: By the way: I think Mico's solution is better than mine. I could not have done it in Mico's LuaTeX-based way because I'm still not experienced enough in Lua. ;-)

Comment: @MattiaBergomi I am glad that you managed to do everything the way you need it. I tend not to redefine default-macros but to write macros with different names. This ensures that macros/macro-packages where it is relied on the defaults being not redefined are not broken by my code.

Comment: @MattiaBergomi About `\let\Oldcos=\cos`: You can do the same with my code: In the definition of `\mycos` replace `\cos` by `\Oldcos`. Then replace `\newcommand\mycos` by `\let\Oldcos=\cos \renewcommand\cos`. As said in my previous comment, I don't recommend patching default-commands, but one of the good things about LaTeX is that everyone is free to design their code according to their own ideas/likings. Patching a LaTeX-command is not always that trivial. Macros defined by `\DeclareRobustCommand` or by `\newcommand`  with optional arguments underlies a mechanisms consisting of several macros.

Comment: @MattiaBergomi I think teaching kids to use parentheses is a good thing. Not just because of functions. Also because of unambiguity. E.g., cos5/cos3 - what is it? Is it cos(5/(cos(3))) or is it (cos(5))/(cos(3)) ? ;-) When it comes to math, I'm a parentheses-fetishist. ;-)  Since I usually don't get along well with calculators -I often make mistakes when typing - , I do a lot of calculations on paper or using programming languages. Placing parentheses helps me to find my errors... And by the way: I saw: sin(x)/cos(x) = in/co ... ;-)

Comment: @MattiaBergomi I remember being about 12 years old when at school the first time encountering trigonometric functions not in maths but in physics class. Back then I always had that picture with the abscissae/ordinatae on the unit-circle in mind...We had a philosophy teacher who enjoyed working across disciplines and philosophizing with us about mathematical terms (e.g., the term "function") and the ontology of mathematical objects. If you stick to Immanuel Kant's terms, mathematics clearly belongs to the transcendental sciences. That are some of the things calculator-keys don't tell you. ;-)

Comment: ;) (by the way, how do you write code here inside comments, as you do above?)

Comment: @MattiaBergomi I put code into backticks: ```Here is some code: `\def\firstoftwo#1#2{#1}` Here is no more code.``` If the code itself contains backticks, too, wrap it into more backticks than occur in the code: `````Here is some code with backticks in it:```\catcode`\a=11\relax```. No more code.````` If you click on "help" while writing a comment, you will be shown a short summary of mini-Markdown-formatting within comments.

Comment: Excellent, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Here's a LuaLaTeX-based solution which works for expressions involving `\sin`, `\cos`, `\tan`, and `\cot`. Their argument can be either 1 or more letters (e.g, `x` or `xy`) or `\` followed immediately by one or more letters, e.g., `\theta` or `\Omega`. The argument can be either free-standing or enclosed in curly braces. There can also be an superscript term, e.g, `^2`, `n`, or (not sure a sane person would ever write this!) `(3!)`.

The code consists of a Lua function called `add_parens` that does all of the work and two LaTeX macros, called `\AddParensOn` and `\AddParensOff`, which activate and deactivate the Lua function. The Lua function performs a lot of separate string substitution operations because, e.g, both `\sin x` and `\sin {x}` have to be changed to `\sin(x)`. And, of course, the code mustn't get tripped up if it encounters `\sin(x)`, i.e., no extra pairs of parentheses must be added in such cases. If you can limit your input text so as to avoid `\sin{x}`, then the substitution operations can be simplified considerably.

Handling expressions with subscripts, e.g, `\log_2 8` or `\log_{10} 1000`, is left as an exercise for the reader. :-)

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{luacode}
%% The 'add_parens' Lua function does most of the work:
\begin{luacode}
```

```lua
function add_parens ( s )
  ll= { "sin" , "cos" , "tan" , "cot" }
  for i=1,#ll do
    s = s:gsub ( "(\\"..ll[i]..")%s+(%a+)"   , "%1(%2)" ) -- \sin x
    s = s:gsub ( "(\\"..ll[i]..")%s-(\\%a+)" , "%1(%2)" ) -- \cos\alpha
    s = s:gsub ( "(\\"..ll[i]..")%s-(%b{})"  , "%1(%2)" ) -- \tan{y}
    s = s:gsub ( "(\\"..ll[i]..")%s-(^%s-%w)%s-(\\?%a+)"  , "%1%2(%3)" ) -- \sin^2 z 
    s = s:gsub ( "(\\"..ll[i]..")%s-(^%s-%w)%s-(%b{})"    , "%1%2(%3)" ) -- \sin^3 {u}
    s = s:gsub ( "(\\"..ll[i]..")%s-(^%s-%b{})%s-(\\?%a+)", "%1%2(%3)" ) -- \cos ^{2} \pi
    s = s:gsub ( "(\\"..ll[i]..")%s-(^%s-%b{})%s-(%b{})"  , "%1%2(%3)" ) -- \cos ^{10} {v}
  end  
  return s
end
```

```tex
\end{luacode}

%% Define two "toggle switch" LaTeX macros:
\newcommand\AddParensOn{\directlua{ luatexbase.add_to_callback 
  ( "process_input_buffer" , add_parens , "AddParens" )}}
\newcommand\AddParensOff{\directlua{ luatexbase.remove_from_callback 
  ( "process_input_buffer" , "AddParens" )}}

\begin{document}
$\sin\alpha \cos {\gamma} \tan xy \sin{z} \cos^2x \cot ^ {(3!)} {\omega}$ 

\medskip
\AddParensOn % enable the Lua function
$\sin\alpha \cos {\gamma} \tan xy \sin{z} \cos^2x \cot ^ {(3!)} {\omega}$

%% make sure the function doesn't operate on terms with parens:
$\sin(\alpha) \cos (\gamma) \tan(xy) \sin(z) \cos ^2(x) \cot ^ {(3!)} (\omega)$

\medskip
\AddParensOff % disable the Lua function
$\sin\alpha \cos {\gamma} \tan xy \sin{z} \cos^2x \cot ^ {(3!)} {\omega}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Well, we don't use LuaLaTeX at work (and I also don't know it very well), but I really appreciate the answer and I'll try to understand it for the future, where maybe I'll switch to it... ;) Any pdflatex-based answer is however still appreciated! :)

Comment: @MattiaBergomi - Until about two or three years ago, LuaLaTeX's output could be quite different from that of pdfLaTeX. That's no longer the case, fortunately. Assuming your TeX distribution is reasonably up to date, switching to LuaLaTeX should not involve much extra work -- if any!

Comment: Yes for my personal interest soon or later I'll try it seriously for sure (being able to use LaTeX with some sort of scripting language is definitely fascinating!), but for the moment the problem above concerns also a lot of colleagues who use pdlatex, as installed and configured at work, so I should still be able to solve it without such a fancy LuaLaTeX approach :) What drives me crazy is that the approach we are using works for ^ and _ alone, but I'm not able to modify the code with the \@ifnextchar to handle both cases... :S